# Отправить изображение и текст одним запросом с помощью java socket

Tags: java, сокет

Все привет! Объявилась проблема в виде клиента на c# и доступа к исходному коду у меня нет. По протоколу, этот клиент должен принимать ответ в виде изображения и текста в одном запросе. От PrintWriter, понятное дело я отказался, поскольку он примитивен и не умеет работать с байтовыми массивами. Использую OutputStream.
Так вот, проблема в том что даже передать текст + число формата 4 байта, при простом копировании двух массивов в один, он уже выдает какую то дичь. С  изображением будет скорее всего еще хуже.
Есть ли в java средства, которые способны передать нормально несколько байтовых массивов за раз?
Пы. Сы. : DataOutputStream не предлагать. Не получилось.
функция сложение массивов:

```
public void write(int len,byte[]...message) throws IOException{
    byte[] array = new byte[len];

    int i=0;
    for(byte[] ar : message)
        for(int j=0;j<ar.length;j++){
            array[i]=ar[j];
            i++;
        }
        socket.getOutputStream().write(array);
}
```

отправка изображения и текста;

```
ImageIO.write(bImage, "JPEG", bos );
    byte[] msg  = sendNumber("number");
    byte[] size = MySocket.intToBytes(bos.size(), 8);// ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putInt(bos.size()).array();      
    byte[] img  = bos.toByteArray();

    byte[] sep1 = MySocket.intToBytes(0x0d, 4);
    byte[] sep2 = MySocket.intToBytes(0x0A, 4);
    System.out.println("отправка номера");

        try {

            map.get("DS").write(msg.length+size.length+img.length+sep1.length+sep2.length,msg,size,sep1,sep2,img);
            map.get("DS").flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

При отправке текст + 4 -ех байтовый формат числа, читает только текстувую часть, вместо числа в логах черные квадратики:

```
byte[]  ar1="200 Ok\r\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[]  ar2=MySocket.intToBytes((int)(1000+Math.random()*9000),4);
byte[]  ar3=MySocket.END_LINE.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

socket.write(ar1.length+ar2.length+ar3.length,ar1, ar2,ar3);
```

Comment: В Java всё необходимое есть, нужно только уметь с этим работать. Добавьте в вопрос спецификацию протокола, ваш код и пример "дичи".

Comment: А зачем слаживать массивы? Что мешает записать в поток последовательно сразу текст, потом изображение?

Comment: Это не возможно, OutputStream записывает массив только один раз, дальше хоть еще 10 массивов запиши, отправится только самый первый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать класс [BinaryWriter](https://github.com/Top-Cat/SteamKit-Java/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/thomasc/steamkit/util/stream/BinaryWriter.java)

```
ImageIO.write(bImage, "JPEG", bos );
    byte[] msg  = sendNumber("number");
    byte[] size = MySocket.intToBytes(bos.size(), 8);// ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putInt(bos.size()).array();      
    byte[] img  = bos.toByteArray();

    byte[] sep1 = MySocket.intToBytes(0x0d, 4);
    byte[] sep2 = MySocket.intToBytes(0x0A, 4);
    System.out.println("отправка номера");

        try {
            int data_len=msg.length+size.length+img.length+sep1.length+sep2.length;
            BinaryWriter bw=new BinaryWriter(4+data_len);
            bw.write(data_len);
            bw.write(msg);
            bw.write(size);
            bw.write(sep1);
            bw.write(sep2);
            bw.write(img);
            socket.getOutputStream().write(bw.toByteArray());
            map.get("DS").flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: Я просто унаследовал соккет и использовал ByteArrayOutputStream который замечательно справляется